# Find broken symbolic link then find respective file in backup and relink

Tags: symlink

I have a lot of broken symbolic links that point to files that do no longer exist in that location, I can find all of them with this oneliner:

```
find . -type l | while read f; do if [ ! -e "$f" ]; then ls -l "$f"; fi; done
```

Which gives me something like this:

```
./17_50.paired.right.fastq.gz -> ../../../../../../../.git/annex/objects/24/P0/SHA256E-s4214107462--c36267de6b6d438d1ea9c0f262be5a873aaffdf8845a42377e159db6a71b404d.gz/SHA256E-s4214107462--c36267de6b6d438d1ea9c0f262be5a873aaffdf8845a42377e159db6a71b404d.gz
```

Now, I do have a backup of the linked files elsewhere, and I would like to use the result of the first oneliner to find the file `SHA256E-s4214107462--c36267de6b6d438d1ea9c0f262be5a873aaffdf8845a42377e159db6a71b404d.gz` in the backup and replace the original link to something like this

```
./17_50.paired.right.fastq.gz -> /path/to/backup/SHA256E-s4214107462--c36267de6b6d438d1ea9c0f262be5a873aaffdf8845a42377e159db6a71b404d.gz
```

How can I do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the prettiest, but it works.

```
find . -type l | while read f
do
    if [ ! -e "$f" ] #if link is broken
        then 
        item=$(ls -l "$f")
        filepath=$(echo "$item" | sed -n 's/^.* \.\/\s*\(\S*\).*$/\1/p') #extract filepath by looking for " ./"
        oldlinkpath=$(echo "$item" | sed -n 's/^.*>\s*\(\S*\).*$/\1/p') #extract linkpath by looking for ">"
        oldlinkfilename=$(basename "$oldlinkpath")
        newlinkpath=$(find /mnt/usbbackup/ppgdata/data -type f -name "$oldlinkfilename") #find file in backup
        rm "$filepath" #remove symlink
        echo "linking $filepath to $newlinkpath"
        ln -s "$newlinkpath" "$filepath" #create new symlink to file in backup
    fi
done
```

1. find all the broken links
2. extract path of broken link
3. find filename of linked file
4. find linked file in backup by its filename
5. change link to location in backup

Once all is done I run 'symlinks -c folder' to change all the absolute paths to relative ones.